# Instantiate a base class inside a child class after construction

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class A:

```
class A(object):
 def __init__(self,x,y):
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
```

Now, let B inherit from A:

```
class B(A):
 def __init(self,x,y,p,q):
  A.__init__(self,x,y)
  self.p=p
  self.q=q
```

Let ex1 be an instance of B:

```
ex1 = B(x1,y1,p1,q1)
```

Is there an elegant way to create an instance of A and have it's attributes be assigned to B? Such that

```
exA = A(x2,y2)

#something like...
ex1.A = exA

#..so that
print(ex1.x) #yields x2
print(ex1.y) #yeilds y2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "copy constructor" if that's what you're getting at - you can't overload `=` in python. But you could easily define a function in class B:

```
def fromA(self,someA):
    self.x = someA.x
    self.y = someA.y
```

Now `ex1.fromA(exA)` will do what you want. You can also define this in `A` itself, might make more sense. If you do define it in `A` or `B`, you can use it in you init if you rather:

```
def __init__(self,p,q,someA):
    self.fromA(someA).
    self.p = p
    self.q = q
```

**EDIT** If you want something to copy all attributes of the parent class, then in the parent class put:

```
def fromA(self,someA):
    for att in someA.__dict__:
        self.__dict__[att] = someA.__dict__[att]
```

If you add stuff outside of `init` this needs to be encased in a try to make sure the attribute exists in the current object.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I thought of doing this way but this option is very clunky. It requires me to keep updating this function everytime I change the base class. The other way I thought of doing this was to compare and change the __dict__ attributes but I don't want to go that far if something more elegant is possible.

Comment: I see. Well there is the option of using the list of attributes of your class in the function, and just looping over all of them. This would not require changing the function. This would also mean you need the function in the parent. Do you want me to show an example or do you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Thanks, yes I know how to do the looping bit. That's what I meant by changing the attributes through `__dict__.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't think there is anything more 'elegant'. I actually consider this pretty nifty.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class method for B that takes A as an argument.

```
class B(A):
    def __init(self, x, y, p, q):
        A.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.p = p
        self.q = q

    @classmethod
    def fromA(cls, A, p, q):
        return cls(A.x, A.y, p, q)
```

Now you can do:

```
exA = A(x2,y2)
exB = B.fromA(exA, p1, q1)

print(exB.x) #yields x2
print(exB.y) #yeilds y2
```